# Why these instructions which should operate on unsigned integers still affect flags used when signed numbers are dealt with?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

It's documented that "INC", "DEC" and "MUL" instructions should be used on unsigned integers but still two first instructions affect overflow and sign flags and "MUL" affects overflow flag which are flags used when dealing with signed numbers and it doesn't make sense with that documentation, So why ?

Comment: The main idea of 2's complement was to use the same `add` operation for both, signed and unsigned values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you get the idea that `inc` and `dec` should be restricted to unsigned integers. Please point me at the pertinent documentation.

*In general*, the 8086 processor didn't have different instructions for signed/unsigned operations.  The processor had built-in knowledge of how the result of an operation would be viewed in a "signed" world, but that's pretty much as far as it went.  And that has been carried through to the latest iterations of the x86 processor design.

It would make little sense to have an `inc` instruction that worked only with unsigned values, as then it would be either very expensive to increment a signed value (you would have to use the `add` or `adc` instruction to add 1), or it would be very expensive to check for overflow after doing the `inc` (or `dec`).

Comment: well, check these links http://home.comcast.net/~fbui/intel_i.html#inc and http://home.comcast.net/~fbui/intel_d.html#dec you'll see it's documented they're for unsigned integers.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you call "documentation". Intel's instruction set reference, http://www.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/24319102.pdf, doesn't say anything about "unsigned" for `inc` or `dec`.  I'd have to dig out my 8086 book from home to see if the original documentation did. That said, the point is that the processor doesn't say whether an operand or result is signed or unsigned--it just lets you know how the result would be viewed if you're interpreting it as a signed quantity.  That's the important thing to understand.

Comment: I see what you say, the intel document indicates the same thing as you say and seems strange that wrox professional assembly language ebook and the link I provided give wrong info in some terms.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are talking x86 here, the [Wikipedia page on the overflow flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag) says it's set by all arithmetic operations.  Which documentation are you referring to that suggests otherwise?

Comment: Well I'm not referring to anything that suggests otherwise, but I think I got the point that is although after all arithmetic operations the overflow flag gets affected, the flag does have its usual usage only after execution of a certain number of those operations and after execution of other operations it's whether set to an unusual value having its unsual usage then, or is set to an undefined value that is useless or it's not affected at all; interesting!.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works:

Consider two byte values 0x65 and 0x31. They are both unsigned values regardless of whether you look at them from a signed or unsigned point of view.

Then you add them:

0x65 + 0x31 becomes 0x96 which is fine from the unsigned point of view (the sum fits in a byte so no carry flag was set). However from the signed view the addition of two positive numbers resulted in a negative number, hence the overflow and sign flags were set. In fact, for all signed numbers the overflow flag is set if the most significant bit changes as a result of the operation, otherwise it is cleared.

You can see it as if the cpu performs two operations for every instruction by setting the applicable flags for both the unsigned and the signed add. After that it is up to the compiler (or assembly programmer) to decide if an unsigned conditional branch (using flags zero and carry) or a signed conditional branch (using flags zero, sign and overflow).

So what's the point?

The point is that if it were not done in this way the processor would need one set of instructions for signed operations (that would only affect the zero, sign and overflow flags) and another for unsigned operations (affecting zero and carry).